# How to know if a conditional independence is true or false

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I'm learning Bayesian networks and I have to "guess" if the following conditional independence are true or false using the following table:

[image]

And the conditional independence are:

1. $I_p(A, B)$
2. $I_p(A, C)$

*p* is the probability distribution.
*A = a*, *B = b*, and *C = c*.

I have no idea about how to know or which operation do I have to do to know if those conditional independence are true or false.

What do I have to do to know if those **conditional independence** are true or false?

Comment: What does the subscript $p$ in $I_p(A,B)$ mean? In fact, what do $A,B,C$ mean and how are they related to the $a,b,c$ in your table?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have updated my question.

Comment: In 1, are you asking about the independence of $A$ and $B$ given $C$? And in 2, $A$ and $C$ given $B$?

Comment: @gunes I don't know. This is something that I don't understand and I'm trying to figure it out what it means. The book that I'm using has a very strange notation.

Comment: which book are you using, and what is the page number?

Comment: @gunes It is a Spanish book. You can find it here: http://www.ia.uned.es/~fjdiez/libros/intro-mgp.pdf And the page number is 32 (or 44 in PDF numeration).

Comment: I've found another book using similar definitions: Learning Bayesian Networks by Neapolitan, which defines these $I_P$ notation in its first Chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that both from your book, and *Learning Bayesian Networks* by *Richard Neapolitan* uses the same notations. I've never come across with the notation $I_P(..)$ while dealing with Bayesian Networks, but it turns out your book is not the only one. This notation simply means *Independence in P* (Neapolitan page ~29). For example, if $P(A|B)=P(A)$, then $I_P(A,B)$, which means $A$ and $B$ are **independent**. If $P(A|B,C)=P(A|C)$ (for all $a,b,c$), then $I_P(A,B|C)$, which means $A$ and $B$ are **independent conditioned on C**.

In your question, you ask for the *conditional* independences $I_P(A,B)$ and $I_P(A,C)$, but according to the definitions there ask for usual independence, not conditional, which can still be referred as conditional independence on *nothing*.

Anyway, either it is conditional or not, we have the full joint distribution and we can calculate any probability we want using the table. For example, a marginal and a two-variable joint can be calculated as follows: $$P(A=a)=\sum_b\sum_c{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}$$ $$P(A=a,B=b)=\sum_c{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}$$
A conditional probability can be calculated using Bayes Law:
$$P(A=a|B=b)=\frac{P(A=a,B=b)}{P(B=b)}$$
$$P(A=a,B=b|C=c)=\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}{P(C=c)}$$

You just need to plug in the numbers and verify that $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ for $I_P(A,B)$ for the first case, assuming it questions independence of $A$ and $B$ conditioned on nothing, based on the definitions in both books.

Comment: The question seems to be about **conditional** independence and not about independence, which is what your answer discusses.

Comment: You are right! I'll edit my answer as soon as I see what $I_p$ is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now the question is how to calculate any probability using the table.

Comment: It's implicitly in the answer. For showing $P(A=a,B=b)=P(A=a)P(B=b)$ is true or not,  you need to evaluate four possible situations: $(a,b)$ in ${(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)}$. You can use the first two formula above.

Comment: I think I have to study more because I still don't know how to use the table. @gunes Thanks a lot.

Comment: @gunes I've found how to use the table!!! I'm happy!